# How to resolve a layout issue?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout based on nested `LinearLayouts`. All fonts are in `sp` and everything else is in `dp`. It displays exactly like I want on emulated platforms like Nexus 10, Nexus 7 and Nexus 5, and I can see it scales well. But when I try on non Google phones with same dimensions of the Nexus 5, some texts appear too big and partly hidden.

What can I do here ?

Here is the layout if it's useful :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/HorizontalLinearLayout">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/lblTempsDePose"/>

        <Spinner
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:id="@+id/spnTempsDePose"
            android:entries="@array/arrayTempsDePose"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/HorizontalLinearLayout">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/lblConstanteLumiereIncidente"/>

        <Spinner
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:id="@+id/spnConstanteLumiereIncidente"
            android:entries="@array/arrayConstanteLumiereIncidente"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/HorizontalLinearLayout">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/lblIso"/>

        <Spinner
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:id="@+id/spnIso"
            android:entries="@array/arrayIso"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/HorizontalLinearLayout">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/lblFiltreDensiteNeutre"/>

        <Spinner
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:id="@+id/spnFiltreDensiteNeutre"
            android:entries="@array/arrayFiltreDensiteNeutre"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/HorizontalLinearLayout">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Label"
            android:text="@string/lblCorrectionExposition"/>

        <Spinner
            style="@style/Spinner"
            android:id="@+id/spnCorrectionExposition"
            android:entries="@array/arrayCorrectionExposition"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/lblRetour"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: may be font in sdp or ssp help you.https://github.com/intuit/sdp ,https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: it might be that the device font is just set to large on your non-Google device as you called it. sp adapts to the device font, try changing in to dp to get static font size

Comment: Curious question why are you using style to horizontally line the nested layouts why not set the orientation on inner layouts to horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the capability to use it the constraint layout would solve this. You can then set the views constraints to other views, window, guidelines, pretty much anything. You can also easily force the views to squeeze into or space depending on needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library [sdp library by intuit](https://github.com/intuit/sdp), it's working great and auto-scale views and layouts. It mainly uses sdp in the place of dp.